# File exist and img src pb

Tags: php

I'm working on a local server on a NAS in a folder named "WEB" with few php scripts including phpMyAdmin.

Beside the "WEB" folder (at the same level) I've got a folder with images named "Imagesfolder".

Unfortunately, for few reasons, I can't put this images folder in the "WEB" folder, but I need to use these images with the php scripts to create pdf files.

What I find surprising is that I can see if a file exists:

`if (file_exists('/volume1/Imagesfolder/photo.jpg')) {`... works fine. ("volume1" is the RAID disk name)  (I thought that file exist couldn't work on with remote folders..) but when I put img src="/volume1/Imagesfolder/photo.jpg" the image isn't found.

Comment: filesize ('/volume1/Imagesfolder/photo.jpg') works too.

Comment: PHP file scope is different than final HTML scope. What's the relative URL of the output and where's the actual location of the PHP file?

Comment: `/volume1/..` is an absolute path physically stored on a disc. the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` (the source of images in the web) is a virtual path and can be mapped to ANY physical path. It's not the same.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted above, absolute paths are not the same as web paths.

You could, as a workaround, try creating a symbolic link if you have console access.

```
ln -s /volume1/Imagesfolder /volume1/WEB/Imagesfolder
```

This will then allow you to do img src="/ImagesFolder/xyz.jpg"

Comment: Thanks I'm going to see this with our administrator.

Comment: Good luck. If that doesn't work, there are some other options but not one-liners, so let us know.